# Conformal iff $E=G$ and $F=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Prove that a parametrization $x(u,v)$ is conformal (angle-preserving) if and only if the coefficients of the first fundamental form satisfy $E=G$ and $F = 0$.

My attempt:

It suffices to consider $e_1$ and $e_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is easy to show that the differential $dx(e_1)=x_u$ and $dx(e_2)=x_v$. Note that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are orthogonal to each other, while $x_u$ and $x_v$ are also orthogonal to each other in the corresponding tangent space.

Now, note that, by assumption, $$\cos \theta = \frac{\langle e_1,e_2\rangle}{\|e_1\|\cdot \|e_2\|} = \frac{\langle x_u,x_v\rangle}{\|x_u\|\cdot\|x_v\|} = \frac{F}{\sqrt{EG}}.$$

However, $\langle e_1,e_2 \rangle=0$ implies $F=0$.

**What about $E$ and $G$?** I appreciate any hints here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $e_1 +e_2$ and $e_1 - e_2$ are perpendicular too.

Comment: That solves my problem lol 
In $\mathbb{R}^2$, we will get $0$ again. In the tangent space we get $E-G$ in the numerator.